# How do I set the ui.bootstrap collapse feature to collapsed on page load?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `ui.bootstrap` and I'm trying to use the [collapse](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mgi8y1Y9fDbyg4s3Vq5p?p=preview) function.

In my code what's happening is the default state is expanded, when the `load weather` button is clicked the `div` is collapsed and after the data has been loaded it expands.

What do I need to do to my code to get it to have a collapsed state on page load and only expand/contract when the button has been clicked?

Here's my code:

```
<div ng-controller="weatherCtrl">
    <div>
        <button ng-model="hotel" class="btn btn-default" 
          ng-click="loadWeather(hotel); isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">load weather</button>
        <hr>
        <div collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.controller('weatherCtrl', function ($scope, weather) {

    $scope.loadWeather = function (hotel) {
        console.log('loadWeather')
        console.log('hotel')
        console.log(hotel)

        weather.get({}, function (data) {
            console.log('data')
            console.log(data)
            $scope.isCollapsed = false;
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using `ng-init` on a parent element:

```
<div ng-controller="weatherCtrl" ng-init="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    <div>
        <button ng-model="hotel" class="btn btn-default" 
          ng-click="loadWeather(hotel)">load weather</button>

        <hr>

        <div collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the click function retained here? You must've also made a change to your controller.

Comment: I'll have a look at my code when I have a min and I'll see what other changes I made.

Comment: I don't know what changes I made but you can view it here: http://hoteldemo.t15.org/responsive/html/